# Flutter lifecycle used with .autoDispose modifier

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I been trying to understand how Riverpod works and was wondering how does it know when to destroy the state of a provider with the .autoDispose modifier when changing a route in Flutter. Is it somehow subscribed to the navigator changes?

The docs state:

```
A common use case is to destroy the state of a provider when it is no-longer used.

There are multiple reasons for doing so, such as:

- When using Firebase, to close the connection and avoid unnecessary cost.
- ***To reset the state when the user leaves a screen and re-enters it.****
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "autoDispose" logic doesn't depend on Flutter-specific logic.
Instead it relies purely on whether a provider is currently being listened or not.

When a route is poped, the associated widgets are destroyed. This causes the `ConsumerWidget`s in that route to stop listening to their "watched" providers.

Then, if a provider now has no more listener, it gets disposed.